# unresolved dependency error: com.atlassian.jwt#jwt-core;1.6.1: not found

Tags: scala, sbt, silhouette

I have imported an existing working project on a new machine and am trying to make it compile. I am getting the following error

```
unresolved dependency: com.atlassian.jwt#jwt-core;1.6.1: not found
```

I read that this library is used in `Silhouette`. I am using `Silhouette` in my project.

My `plugins.sbt` is

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/"
```

I notice that that IntelliJ is trying to find the library in the following places but it isn't able to.

```
==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\UserName\.ivy2\local\com.atlassian.jwt\jwt-core\1.6.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/atlassian/jwt/jwt-core/1.6.1/jwt-core-1.6.1.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-pluginstub\preloaded\com.atlassian.jwt\jwt-core\1.6.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/sbt-global-pluginstub/preloaded/com/atlassian/jwt/jwt-core/1.6.1/jwt-core-1.6.1.pom
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding `resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo` in `build.sbt`. I don't know why this issue occurred now though. Maybe I already had the jar in my previous machine as I use Bitbucket and had downloaded their Sourcetree application

Comment: Adding `jcenterRepo` did not work for me. I added this to resolve `resolvers += "Atlassian Maven" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/"`

Answer (score 3):

My problem was, that I must add it to the **`build.sbt`** not `plugin.sbt`, like

`resolvers in ThisBuild += "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/"`